# Html.TextBoxFor max length only count numbers mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to only count numbers but my textarea count also counts comma with number. How can I solve this problem?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Money, new { @class = "w90 amount-align",
                                     @id = "input-amount", 
                                     @maxlength = 11",
                                     @data_mask = "###.###.###", 
                                     @data_mask_reverse = "true",
                                     @Placeholder = "0" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget it. The maxlength input attribute only work with the input value char count. Wherever if it is number, currency, text, etc.

Then, you will need to develop your own customMaxLength by your self. Something like this.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="field" class="maxlength-5">
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('.maxlength-5').keypress(function(evt){
        var maxLength = 5; // as it threat maxlength-5 custom class :)

        // assuming that data-mask will certify that only currency format will be valid        
        var pureValue = $(this).val().replace('.','').replace(',',''); 

        if(pureValue.length >= maxLength)
            evt.preventDefault();
});
```

});

Try it yourself [here](http://jsfiddle.net/o3mxjLdn/).

Comment: you misundertood me. I want to input like 12345678999 than its change like 12.345.678.999 but not count dot this has to be 11 char but my code says that this is 14 char.

Comment: I tried for a few hours to find some jquery masked input cdn to build a Fiddle sample. Try this: at `Focus()`, call the `.unmask()` method.  With this you may use the maxlength default validation and the plugin masking feature.